# What happens to my reputation when I undelete my answer?

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-answers

I am aware that, if my answer is downvoted and I delete it, I gain my reputation back. But if two days later I change my mind and undelete that answer, and the votes stay the same, what happens to my reputation?

I ask because, while I assumed that my reputation would go back down, this doesn't seem to have happened when I tried it today (on [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029282/getting-resource-as-stream-returns-inputstream-must-not-be-null/31029438#31029438) [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31056036/is-this-a-short-hand-variable-declaration/31056156#31056156) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31040257/convert-a-word-docx-file-to-a-pdf-in-c-sharp-on-cloud-environment/31040324#31040324)). It has been over an hour at the time I'm writing this since I undeleted my answer(s), and I haven't noticed any reputation change.

I'm talking about your average, everyday, ordinary answers here (i.e. no Community Wiki special cases), by the way.

Is this a bug? Is it a cache delay? I find the latter hard to believe, because the cache delay when I first *deleted* the answer(s) was much shorter than an hour.

If this is a bug, it should be fixed to avoid abuse (someone could post an answer, receive downvotes, delete that answer, then later undelete it for 0 net reputation loss).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the rep cap eats the down votes in any answer of yours you linked.

A bit explanation:

- you've posted an answer.
- you got a down vote.
- you have reached the rep cap and **exceeded it** (i.e. 200 reps from up votes per day)
- you delete your answer, but the rep for **the day you capped is recalculated**, you get the down votes again recorded, but they are compensated by the up votes you got that day after reaching the cap.

Comment: As I said in my question, this was two days after the question was deleted. I'll edit the question for clarity.

Comment: @Red a link would help.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'm editing the question with more details.

Comment: Which rep cap are you talking about? When I undeleted those posts, I was far below the rep cap for today. Is there a negative rep cap as well?

Comment: @Red Now, is it clear?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. But I haven't experienced this before. Previously, I have exceeded the rep cap, then received a downvote, but my reputation was not recalculated. Does this recalculation apply only for previous days, and not the current day?

Comment: @Red for all your rep history.

Comment: Yesterday, three of my answers were accepted, so I effectively had a rep cap of 245. However, after I exceeded that cap, I received a downvote, but my rep for yesterday is (and I assume will continue to be) 243 instead. Why is that?

Comment: @Red Because the downvotes was after you reached the cap. That's by design. In the case you ask, the downvotes you got on those answers were before the cap.

Comment: Oh, I see now. When a downvote is reapplied to an undeleted post, it acts as if it happened at the time when it was originally cast? That makes sense, thanks.

Comment: @RedRobo Exactly.